# Is it relevant to use both batch_norm and dropout in estimator?

Tags: tensorflow, batch-normalization, dropout

I read batch normalization and dropout are two different ways to avoid overfitting in neural networks. Is it relevant to use both in the same estimator as following ?

````
```
  model1 = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns_complex_standardized,
                                    hidden_units=[512,512,512],
                                    optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001, beta1= 0.9,beta2=0.99, epsilon = 1e-08,use_locking=False),
                                    weight_column=weights,
                                    dropout=0.5,
                                    activation_fn=tf.nn.softmax,
                                    n_classes=10,
                                    label_vocabulary=Action_vocab,
                                    model_dir='./Models9/Action/',
                                    loss_reduction=tf.losses.Reduction.SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE,
                                    config=tf.estimator.RunConfig().replace(save_summary_steps=10),
                                    batch_norm=True)
````

Comment: I thank both of you for your answers. I understand batch normalization reduces covariate shift but I also read it could help to reduce overfitting. My problem is that my model quick reach almost 0.95 accuracy and then variate between high (0.97)and very low value (0.20 - 0.40). Average loss and  train loss increase too. I think it is a typical case of overfitting, so i asked myself if batch normalization and dropout can be used in the same time or are incompatible methods.

Answer (score 1):

There is a small problem in your understanding. `Batch Normalization` original intent is not to reduce overfitting but to speed up the training. Just like how you normalize the inputs while you are passing it to the first layer of your network, batch normalization achieves this action in inner (or hidden) layers. Batch normalization removes the effect of `covariate shift` while it is training.

But since this is applied at every batches separately, it results in a side effect of regularizing your weight parameters. This regularizing effect is quite similar to that of how you would have done had you intended to solve over-fitting.

You can apply both `batch_norm` and `dropout` together but it is advisable to reduce the dropout. Currently, your dropout rate at 0.5 is very high. I believe dropout of 0.1 to 0.2 should be enough when you are applying it together with `batch_norm`. Also, the value of dropout is a hyper-parameter, so there is no fixed answer to it and you may have to tune it as per your data input and network.

Answer (score 1):

Both `batch normalization` and `dropout` gives the regularization effect in some way or another.

As you apply the `batch normalization` for normalization steps it sees all the training example in `mini-batch` together to reduce the `internal covariate shift` which helps in speeding up the training and not setting the learning rate low and also gives the regularization effect.

If `batch normalization` is used along the network, then the `dropout` regularization can be reduced or dropped in strength